# Where can I get a list of "bad" IP addresses that are likely to be used by attackers or spammers?

Tags: attack-prevention, ddos, spam

Is there an open source project or a list of "bad" IP addresses or ranges that are likely to be used by attackers or spammers?

UPDATE: ideally I want it to be a service call so I can call it using HttpClient or with JSON from my web page and get a yes/no 
(I find it hard to believe that no one has yet created such a web service)

Comment: Yes, you can get some information on this topic with a Google Search:<br>
http://www.mcafee.com/threat-intelligence/ip/spam-senders.aspx

Comment: There are so many "bad" IP addresses and there are so many new ones being added each day and so many that fall off the "bad" list every day, by the time you had a chance to do anything with the list, it would be out-of-date.

Comment: Have you done any research on this topic? There are tons of various types of lists like this available.

Comment: Such a list isn't really useful, as it changes within minutes. Treat every IP address with the same restriction. One thing to note, if the address matches 127.* or 192.168.*, the hacker is already close nearby.

Comment: Given the moving target of compromised servers, individual computers, all addresses are a possible attack source. There is no such thing as a trusted source on the internet. While you might put a permanent block on netblocks like the RBN, it's only a small subset of potential attack vectors

Comment: When using such lists you will experience false positives. Is it really worth the risk?

Comment: For IPv4: `0.0.0.0/0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there an open source project or a list of "bad" IP addresses that are likely to be used by attackers or spammers?

What you looking for are open source Threat Intel feeds. There are a number of them you can subscribe to or likely query. Here are a handful I know of and should lead you in the right direction.

- Collection of long [list of lists](https://github.com/mlsecproject/combine/wiki/Threat-Intelligence-Feeds-Gathered-by-Combine) on GitHub.
- [Emerging Threats](http://rules.emergingthreats.net/)
- [AlienVault](http://labs.alienvault.com/labs/index.php/projects/open-source-ip-reputation-portal/download-ip-reputation-database/)
- [Zues Tracker](https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/blocklist.php)
- [Palevo Tracker](https://palevotracker.abuse.ch/blocklists.php)
- [Abuse.ch](https://www.abuse.ch)
- [Malc0de List](http://malc0de.com/bl/)
- [Binary Defence List](http://www.binarydefense.com/banlist.txt)

Comment: plus malwaredomains.com, email blacklists, and on and on ...

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start, I would love to find a web service that has the most recent information... I'm still looking... or maybe I should write one :-)

Comment: For something more dynamic, you may want to use the prowl.lupovis.io API and block  proactively based on what comes from the API - as oppososed to bulk block.

Answer (score 3):

> UPDATE: ideally I want it to be a service call so I can call it using HttpClient or with JSON from my web page and get a yes/no (I find it hard to believe that no one has yet created such a web service)

HTTP is too much overhead for such a simple task and does not scale that well. Such things are usually done with DNS and there are lots of such lists out there. Just search for [DNSBL](https://www.google.com/search?q=dnsbl).